# background page has no permission

Tags: permissions, google-chrome-extension, manifest

Permissions set in manifest.json don't seem to be affecting my background page. While working on my script, I had it running out of the pop up and it worked perfectly. The same script doesn't work in the background page, however. Upon inspecting it I see that access to the external website is forbidden. Can someone explain why permissions are only working in the popup? I know it's possible to have permissions in the background after seeing other extensions, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Please provide your manifest, your popup code and your background code.

Comment: Unless backgrounds are supposed to have the same permissions as popups, I can't imagine any errors in my code. Everything is labeled correctly, and it clearly attempts to execute the code, the only difference is that, with the same script, it returns the error that it is forbidden from the background page.

Comment: That's like taking a broken car to a mechanic and not letting them look under the hood because you can't imagine there might be something wrong there.

Comment: Clearly you have no answers for me, and I doubt handing out my source would change that. I expect someone who's encountered this problem before to answer as they have experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently background pages must include the subdomain name - even www.
So http://website.com won't work but http://www.website.com will.